# How to dynamically add value in combo box using c sharp?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, visual-studio

Hi
I want to allow user to add new country names in combo box if his/her desired country is not listed in combo box. so next time this value should be add in combo box as well. I want to do this using c sharp.
Kindly guide me.

Comment: Is it Asp.Net or WinForms? They are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean winforms:
These will only be available locally. On a Button-Click, save the data to one of these:

- Textfile
- XML-file
- SQLCE Database

You should find more than enough tutorials with a *your-favorite-search-engine*-search like "c# save and read data to X"
When you read the data again, simply add it to your combobox using `combobox.items.add("country");` oor use the `DataSource`-property.

Assuming you mean ASP.net:
Save them to your database.